# Get the actual array of rows from SQL query with sqlite and Expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sqlite, react-native, expo

I am trying to get the whole result as array of rows from sqlite query results object:

I have tried `results.rows.item(i).id` and it work just fine but I need to get the whole array of rows instead of only one item, i tried to use `rows.array (_number)` from Expo documentation but I can't figure out how actually to use `.array(_number)`

my code snippet:

```
iris.transaction(tx => {
    tx.executeSql(
        `select id, date from days`,
        [],
        (tx, results) => {
            for(i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++){
                var date = results.rows.item(i).date.split('-');
            }
        }
    )
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [Expo document](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/sqlite/#resultset-objects), the `result.rows` has an `_array` which returns all the items as array, you can try like

```
if (result && result.rows && result.rows._array) {
  /* do something with the items */
  // result.rows._array holds all the results.
}
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: As an added note for TypeScript users, it seems that TypeScript really doesn't like `SQLResultSetRowList` - when I try to use `rows._array`, I get an array saying the property `_array` does not exist on type `rows`.

So, if you run into this, just reassign the `rows` object to a new variable and cast it to type `any` - you'll lose the validation, but you won't have the annoying error anymore!

Comment: @ArmandoVasquez thanks, it works. You should really consider writing this in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript Solution to cast _array properly without using any ;)

```
tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM ITEMS", [], (_, { rows }) => {
  const r = rows as unknown as { _array: MyItem[] };
  result = r._array;
});
```